# mysql will not use group by on mac os this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Oh mysql why oh why?

This query works on rds

```
SELECT pair, max(utc_dt) as utc_dt, `value` FROM qta.time_series WHERE ticker='spot_ticker' AND time_interval='DAILY'
and pair = 'AED' group by pair, utc_dt
```

On my local mysql here is the error:

```
Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #3 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 
'test.dyde.value'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How is this possible? I live by group by clauses

I installed the dmg from oracle on mac os.

Where is the my.cnf?

Comment: _"How is this possible? I live by group by clauses"_ - well how is it that your query doesn't have one then?

Answer (score 4):

Do this in terminal to find correct path for my.cnf: 
`mysql --help | grep ".cnf"`
The result of this command is:

```
order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

If not exist `/etc/my.cnf` you can create it:
`sudo vi /etc/my.cnf`
After that add this to `/etc/my.cnf` (If exists `/etc/my.cnf`add this to the end of the file):

```
[mysqld]  
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Finally, restart MySQL

Comment: If you are using version 8.x you will need to remove the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER from the string.  It is no longer supported and the Mysql server will not start if you include it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mysql console

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

This solution wotk fine on Mysql 5.7.11.

Comment: It is not a permanent solution. After a restart, sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing full GROUP BY queries, that will always run.
Each element in the "SELECT" clause should be wither an aggregate expression, or included in the "GROUP BY" clause.

```
SELECT pair, max(utc_dt) as utc_dt, `value` 
FROM qta.time_series 
WHERE ticker='spot_ticker' AND time_interval='DAILY'
    and pair = 'AED' 
GROUP BY pair, utc_dt, `value`
```

Answer (score 0):

Running MacOS Mojave (10.14.6) and native install of MySQL (not Homebrew) as its own user, I had to use the config location of /usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/etc/my.cnf (with a symlink from /usr/local/@mysql/etc/my.cnf). With the following contents:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Setting it there makes it persist across sessions.